# Error: Cannot convert ('selected lines') to int

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

this is my first post in StackOverflow hope it will be understandable.

I'm new at making Google Sheets Script.

I want to do a script that performs a custom search in a Google Sheets document. It prompts the user to enter a value to search for, and then searches for that value in a specific range of cells in the "DATA" sheet. If any matches are found, it hides all rows except for the matching ones in the active sheet. If no matches are found, it displays a message indicating that no results were found.

But I have a problem, when I use my script, it hide all the rows and find the rows that corresponds but don't show it and an error appears

> Error: Cannot convert ('selected lines') to int

Can you help me ? And do you have tips for me ?

Here is my code :

```
function search() {
    var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var valeurRecherchee = Browser.inputBox("Recherche personnalisée", "Entrez la valeur à rechercher :", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  
    if (valeurRecherchee === "cancel") {
      return;
    }
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATA');
    // var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange('A1:M100');
    var queryResult = dataSheet.getRange('A1:M100').createTextFinder(valeurRecherchee).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
    var filteredRows = queryResult.map(function (cell) {
      return cell.getRow();
    });
    if (filteredRows.length === 0) {
      Browser.msgBox("Aucun résultat trouvé pour la recherche : " + valeurRecherchee);
      return;
    }
    feuille.getRange('2:100').activate();
    feuille.hideRows(2, 99);
  
    feuille.showRows(filteredRows);
  }
  feuille.showRows(filteredRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search and keep matching and hide the rest

```
function keepmatchinghiderest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 1;//search start row
  const r = ui.prompt("Search Dialog", "Enter Search String", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let krows = [];
    let rg = sh.getRange("A1:M100");
    let rgs = rg.createTextFinder(r.getResponseText()).findAll();
    if (rgs && rgs.length > 0) {
      rgs.forEach(r => {
        krows.push(r.getRow());
        krows = [...new Set(krows)];
      })
    }
    let obj = [...Array.from(new Array(rg.getHeight()).keys(), x => x + sr)].reduce((acc, r, i) => {
      let idx = krows.indexOf(r);
      if (!~idx) {
        acc.hide.push(r);
      } else {
        if (acc.hide && acc.hide.length > 0) {
          let row = acc.hide[0];
          let cnt = acc.hide.length;
          sh.hideRows(row, cnt);
          acc.hide = [];
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, { hide: [] });
    if (obj.hide && obj.hide.length > 0) {
      let row = obj.hide[0];
      let cnt = obj.hide.length;
      sh.hideRows(row, cnt);
    }
  }
}
```